# What is this blue butterfly?

Tags: magicite

In Magicite in the starting forest biome there is this winged blue thing that hovers around a small grey plant as seen below:

[image: Blue butterfly]

I haven't been able to interact with it using any of the three basic tools or anything else that I've tried.

What is this thing and what are it's purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those winged things are [Elemental bugs](http://magicite.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Bug). You can catch them with a Bug Net (Stick + Net [String + String])

You can use them for a small number of recipes, but the main use is creating a magic wand. If you combine two bugs of the same element into a gem and then combine them with a Stick, you can get a magic wand that uses your mana pool:

- Fireball (Horizontal moving projectile)
- Thunder (Vertical Pillar)[My Preference]
- Frostshard (Shield that pushes enemies away)

You can also use them to upgrade Zweihanders, which is a nice endgame weapon. They do additional damage as well as cast the spell above on attack.